# Why is marriage necessary for intercourse to be lawful? Even if married, it doesn't mean that intercourse is not harmful. STD is possible

Tags: halal-haram, nikah

Please clarify my question, I am confused.

Comment: Why the heck did you change the question even after the answer has already been posted.!?

Comment: You can't delete or change your question after it has been answered. If you want to ask something else then post a new question.

Comment: @User10668 - Editing the questions only creates confusion to the new readers. Kindly don't do it again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the risk of having such diseases is much reduced if a couple is having intercourse only with each other rather than with different people.

Secondly, It is Allah who has ordered us to get married in order to have intercourse. There is no questioning to Allah's orders. Most of the things that Allah has ordered have their answers in Quran and which answers are not available Allah simply isn't telling us rather than just to obey His command.

We come to this site to seek answers from either Quran or Hadiths. But if you question the ayats of Quran itself and there is no use..